# Add and Navigate to a new view in Single Application

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

This question might have been answered, if yes, please share the link.

I have created a Single View Application, It works fine, but now I have added a new view and on a button click, wants the new view to appear.

This is the code for click action,

```
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES];
```

The Default ViewController now looks like this in .h file

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

The SettingsViewController.m has a default

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{}
```

Can I add another view to "Single View Application" like this or should I chose another template for my project ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you use storyboards or interface builder to build your views or did you do it all programmatically?

Comment: I have created a new project without storyboard and have used Interface Builder to design the view.

Comment: I suggest you to start with an empty app and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `UINavigationController` in your `AppDelegate`.  Then make your `ViewController` the `rootViewController` of the `UINavigationController`.  Then you will be able to push and pop views.

Here is the code to create the `rootViewController` where `mainNavigationController` is the `UINavigationController` in your `AppDelegate`:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
mainNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
```

Once you have the `ViewController` set up as the `rootViewController` it will conform to the `UINavigationController` push and pop methods to create a stack of `UIViewController`s.

Answer (score 1):

That is fine. The single view application template is just a barebones template. You can add any type of navigation you like to it.

Comment: For above code, did you see anything wrong, because I cannot made it switch to settingView when the butting is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5, switching between views works a bit different i think,

I have created a few apps with the above mentioned code for switching views.

But now, I have to write it like this to work:

```
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentModalViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: The code in your answer is presenting a ModalViewController.  The code in the question is pushing a ViewController onto the NavigationController Stack.  Both work if they are set up correctly.

Comment: Then I might be doing something wrong in my code, I'll try again.

Comment: Yes, you are right, now its working both ways and this [exmaple/tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews) helped me out to fix thinks